# Janus WEBRTC issue on media stream conection stability

Tags: live-streaming, janus, janus-gateway

**Here my scenario :**

I have a Janus gateway deployed on Oracle cloud and on the front end there is a Room containing a Local stream(Presenter) and Remote stream(viewer). In the janus room we have exchanging the Audio and Video stream with each other to collaborate on the topics.  The connection was successfully established and we were able to communicate with each other.

**Problem Statement**
I have initiated a Presenter with 4 viewers. The room seamlessly processed during the initiation and in the random case the viewer stream struk with the black screen fraction of second and again started working normally. So far we are facing this issue only on the viewer side and the presenter stream works fine.

**My Observation**

1. If there is any unstable or insufficient bandwidth to cause this issue?
2. The viewer put the Room in background and started working on the new tab on the browser?
3. CPU utilization on the system?

Any one facing this issue on your side, If So kindly guide us how we resolve this glitch during the above scario's. Else any other root cause you guys know about the issues. The Janus room stream will be seamlessly stream without the black screen and to be handled smartly this problem. Issues facing across all the machines like Linux, Windows and Mac chrome browser.

**Configuration**

1. Video stream (720, 480)
2. Various fps

Comment: There are **so many** reasons this can happen.  You'll need to at least figure out what side of all this the problem is on.  You mention that you have a fixed video stream size, but are you also aware that the video may arbitrarily change size midstream?  CPU and bandwidth limitations can cause this.

Comment: Thanks for responding, and we have not set a fixed video. It has been adaptive stream. As mentioned the issue happened regardless of any quality of video stream (720, 480, ect)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the reason via chrome://webrtc-internals.

Find you connection and inspect "inbound-rtp (kind=video..." section - if there any packetsLost (it means network issue or low bandwidth), pauseCount / freezeCount (if zero and black screen appears - problem is in the sender's side) etc.